# OSError: libtorch_cuda.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, torchaudio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sf3Tn.png)
I have been stuck with this problem for a while, and I would be very grateful if someone could help me resolve it. The system I am using is Ubuntu with CUDA 12.0.

As mentioned, I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling torchaudio, but I still encounter the same issue.

Comment: Check this https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/90673#issuecomment-1563799299 maybe it helps

Comment: @MarcelFerrari This leads to another error: OSError: libtorch_cuda_cpp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. But cheers the error is different

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me as well. If you installed pytorch with conda, it has some issues recognizing which build is the right one. I guess you have a cpu build, but have pytorch-conda installed and want to use it with the gpu.

To solve it either you run (create a fresh environment otherwise it might not work)

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=12.1 -c pytorch -c nvidia
```

as described on the [pytorch webpage](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/).

Or you can tell conda which build of pytorch you want to have exactly ([here](https://anaconda.org/pytorch/pytorch/files) are all the builds available, you need one with `*cuda*` instead of `*cpu*`)

For example in my case

```
conda install pytorch=2.1.0=py3.11_cuda11.8_cudnn8.7.0_0 -c pytorch
```

solved the issue.